# Can you avoid loading reusable components that another page already loaded them

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I have a page (let's call it Page1) that use is loaded dynamically via React.lazy that uses several reusable components and another page (Page2) that uses some of those reusable components, this page being as well loaded dynamically.

My question would be, is there a way to prevent Page2 to load those reusable components again?

When I analyze the generated final bundle I see that both pages load the reusable components individually and I think ideally would be to just load them once and each new dynamically loaded page that uses those reusable components shouldn't fetch them again.

Comment: I think what you are talking about here is "tree-shaking", which is typically implemented via webpack.  Tree-shaking is a way to only the load the pieces of a codebase which are actually used in the current code.  Your app won't load the `React.lazy` pages until they are needed, and it *should* deduplicate the code for the reusable components so that it's not loaded twice.  It should be configured properly out of the box if you are using Create React App.

Answer (score 0):

Reusable components as like simple components act as individual distinctive when used in different code files. so they will surely re-render again when used in other files.